# Extract external image url from Facebook rss feed

Tags: php, facebook

I have a Facebook page Feed that looks like this,

```
http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA-U_vFlmf0YW5c&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FX9Hx6nUTSwE%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg%3Ffeature%3Dog
```

How to extract what comes between the &url.........featuredog (Extracting only image url) ?
Appreciate any code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my regex is ugly but does the trick:

```
<?php
$str = 'http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA-U_vFlmf0YW5c&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FX9Hx6nUTSwE%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg%3Ffeature%3Dog';

$str = urldecode($str);
preg_match_all('~&url=(.*?)[\?\!]?feature~i', $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

echo $matches[1][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = parse_url('http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA-U_vFlmf0YW5c&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FX9Hx6nUTSwE%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg%3Ffeature%3Dog');
parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
var_dump($params['url']);
```